# Commenting out code in Atom will give me an error

Tags: react-native, atom-editor

I am using Atom editor for my react-native project. When I comment out my code in Atom, and run it, I will get an error saying that Text string must be rendered within a  component.

I think this is Atom editor issue. I can comment out code using `cmd + /` but this will throw me an error when I run the code.

```
class RegisterScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <View style={{flex:1}}>
//this is profile text
      <View style={{width:'100%', height:70, justifyContent:'flex-start', alignItems:'flex-start',backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
        <Text style={{paddingLeft:20, paddingTop:20, fontSize: 20, fontWeight:'bold'}}> profile </Text>
      </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: show some commented code, maybe you commented out a bracket by accident

Comment: I just edited my question.

Comment: to comment out code in template, I believe it needs to be the `<!--` and `-->` pair.

Comment: actually the error happens when I leave a comment and using `cmd+/`

Comment: if you manually comment out your code using  `<!--` and `-->` and it returns no error, then it confirms that Atom's commenting feature for the react file is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, comments in JSX need to be enclosed by curly braces (see [How to comment in JSX](https://wesbos.com/react-jsx-comments/)):

```
{/* A JSX comment */}
```

You probably would have noticed the syntax error from the highlighting, but the default JavaScript syntax package doesn't catch it. For comparison, here's how [language-javascript-jsx](https://atom.io/packages/language-javascript-jsx) highlights your comment:

[image]

Both packages correctly display comments enclosed by curly braces:

[image]

Consider reporting the [issue](https://github.com/atom/language-javascript/issues), so the developers can fix the logic of the *Toggle Comment* command inside JSX.

Answer (score 0):

It is an Atom editor issue. The correct way to write comments in jsx is `{/*Your comment here*/}`